# Draw controls in tab control tab header area in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, ownerdrawn

I am trying to add some controls to the left of the tab header area for my tab control but not affect the tab page area (like internet explorer). I think I would have to owner draw the control, but I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you searched before you ask you question mate ?!!
there are many articles outside. I think the following links are exactly what you want, take a look.

[Y(et)A(nother)TabControl: A Custom Tab Control With Owner Drawn Tabs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/yatabcontrol.aspx)

[TabStrip Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/tabstrips.aspx)

hope this help.

Comment: So it looks like I need to throw out the tab control entirely to achieve this result?