# Indent tab in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, tabcontrol, custom-draw

I'd better illustrate what I want to achieve.

Original:                         Desired:

[image: original tab]                  [image: desired tab position]

Any ideas how to draw tabs in this way? Thanks.

Comment: Is it puzzle to find how many character are in this picture?!

Comment: @DeveloperX,  No, it's "Where's Valdo?". In case the question is not clear, the idea is to move the tab a little bit to the right.

Comment: Do you want to do that in your own code or any third party components?

Comment: @DeveloperX I want to do it in my own code, but I'll appreciate any links to third-party controls which implement such functionality.

Comment: The native Windows tab control doesn't support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found this post in stack overflow ,I think it is what you want
[Draw controls in tab control tab header area in Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321834/draw-controls-in-tab-control-tab-header-area-in-winforms)

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, as for now I'm using this component http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/ThemedBottomTabNET.aspx . It looks promising, I've already managed to draw tabs the way I want and now it just needs some minor tweaks.

Comment: Yes,I visited that one,its good but I thought it was'nt what you want

Answer (score 1):

You should set a margin for your first tab. Like this:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="Tab" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is WinForms. Edited tags.